Real Estate Partition Suit with Negative Equity
What happens in a partition suit if a valuation skews negative? Can a court render judgment against a party for his or her share in the negative equity? And what would the remedies be?
Can one be forced to bring cash to table, so that a short sale or foreclosure does not occur?

The usual remedy in a partition action, absent an agreement to the contrary by the parties, is for the court to order the property sold at a sheriff's sale that is basically identical to a foreclosure sale (assuming that the property cannot feasibly be physically divided in kind into two separate useable parcels of equal value). A lienholder of record is a necessary party to a partition action.
A lien, in this sense of the word, is any debt obligation for which the property is collateral, regardless of whether it is a mortgage, a deed of trust, a mechanic's lien, a judgment lien, a property tax lien, a tax lien, etc.
If the sale produces less than the outstanding debt, then the lienholder receives all of the proceeds, less the costs of sale, and the lender can secure a deficiency judgment for the balance owed against the people obligated on the underlying debt.
Usually, everyone obligated on the debt would be jointly and severally liable, and would have a right to contribution from the other people obligated on the deficiency judgment if that person ends up paying more than their share of the deficiency judgment to the creditor.

You might note that depending upon local (state or provincial) law, a deficiency judgment may or may not be available to the creditor after such a foreclosure. For example, in California, a creditor may foreclose either non-judicially (by hiring, for example, a foreclosure company) or judicially (by filing a lawsuit and proceeding in court). In California, deficiency judgments are available only after judicial foreclosures.

@DavidRecallsMonica An award to secured creditors in a partition action sale isn't, strictly speaking, a foreclosure at all and certainly isn't a non-judicial foreclosure.
